# Firefox browser doesn't switch back to main window after opening new tab

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

`FirefoxDriver` doesn't switch back to main window after opening new tab.. This works perfectly fine on `ChromeDriver`..

I've a main webpage with multiple `<a>` elements/links and I want to open each link in a new tab and then switch back to main page.

`FirefoxDriver` is not treating the new tab as a windowHandle.. when I try to print the size of window handles it is returning just one in `FirefoxDriver` whereas it's returning two in `ChromeDriver`which is fine..

```
driver.get(url);
WebElement webelement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]"));
List<WebElement> allLinks = webelement.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

int totalSize = listofSites.size();


int splitedvalue = totalSize / Integer.parseInt(split2);
int startValue = splitedvalue * (Integer.parseInt(split1) - 1);

        for( int i= startValue ; i<endValue; i++  ){

            links_URL.add(allLinks.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            String url = allLinks.get(i).getAttribute("href");

            String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
            allLinks.get(i).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);   

            tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);


            }

        for( int k= 1 ; k< tabs2.size(); k++  ){
            System.out.println("size of tab2 "+tabs2.size());

            for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
             driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(k));

            }
            routeToproperloginpage(emailID, password, url_array.get(k-1) );   
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
        }

    }
```

Comment: When you open link in a new tab the control will still be there in the main page. Can you eloborate your problem more and post a detailed code  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: updated the code.. well, all the newly open tab has the same window handler ID.. something like below.. including main webpage..{70174a6b-8a18-4988-8579-e706a64371fc}
and window handles always returns size 1 regardless of tab opened

Comment: just a suggestion: sometimes new firefox versions have problems with webdriver compatibility, so updating webdriver version or downgrading firefox browser can resolve issues tagged "works perfectly fine in browser x"